# How is this question not spam?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I just flagged [this question (Id: 37097146)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097146/how-i-can-view-google-directory-bizimkecid-tk) as spam, because the way I see it:

1. It asks an off-topic question while
2. aggressively promoting the domain in both the title and the content, therefore I concluded that it
3. "exists only to promote a product or service" and it did not
4. properly "disclose the author's affiliation."
5. As far as I can see it had the [appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appengine) tag simply to have any tag
6. Also it did not give any kind of context, so there is no way we could've been able to answer the question without tons of comments, which would've been off-topic on Stack Overflow anyway.
7. I did not want to flag the question as off-topic since moving it to any other Stack Exchange site would've been pointless.

The flag was declined because the moderator "found no evidence to support it".

What would have been the proper cause of action / the right flag?

Since the question is on hold now I can't see what happened to the question, it would've been education though.

[image]

Comment: @David thanks for adding the screenshot. Interesting that the question was basically closed as "why isn't this code working?". I'd expect that reason for questions that are essentially on-topic but lack the required information to actually provide help.

Comment: Such stuff are really out of my expertise (I'm just a statistician), so I can't really judge if this spam or not. One could think that their issue is essentially coding related and with some fixes it should give the desired output. Hence, if it was up to me I wouldn't think it is necessarily spam neither, rather a "*why isn't my code working*". Though, usually questions that being put on hold not being instantly erased rather the OP is being encouraged to edit his question if they want it be reopened again. The fact it was instantly erased seem to imply Martin thought it was a fishy one too..

Comment: I didn't decline that flag. Your flag was probably declined because that post is still related to computing in general and the link used in it is not in our "known spam list" and the OP is not "directly promoting" his site ("come learn PHP at xyz.pq" -> spam)

Comment: @TheLostMind So why was it deleted then? Isn't the propose of putting a question on hold is ["*meant to convey that the question requires improvement and may be reopened if improved*"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question) or there is just no other way to delete it otherwise?

Comment: @TheLostMind I don't think you can define promotion as an appeal to performing an action on a certain site. If it were, then posting a collection of links to sites offering performance enhancers with a question like "How can i programmatically detect whether these performance enhancers are the real thing" would be a valid question even though the intention would clearly be to promote the sites. I dare say that if a posting (be it question or answer) is made up of 20% or more links to websites, then the post smells like promotion. There's a reason why we don't like link-only answers.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - Blatantly off-topic questions can be deleted. That doesn't make them "spam". A post that is VLQ can be deleted, that does not make it spam / abusive. The penalties that are applied to spam are different from those applied to posts deleted because of their quality

Comment: @konqi - You have taken an example that is easy to handle. If there is a question  - "I get some JS error when I click a button on my website. <site link here>", we cannot mark it as spam. It would be really tempting to "assume" that this could be spam, but we will have to ensure that our actions (flagging it as spam) don't hurt a person who wasn't actually spamming. IMHO, if something isn't definitely spam ("Online tutorial <here>" or "Get fair skin .." ), then it shouldn't be treated as spam. Note that if that post was on a different question, it would have been a different story.

Comment: @TheLostMind yours would be a "why isn't this code working" because the question is on-topic but requires a lot more context (code sample, etc.). I very much agree there. This question however was off-topic (unsalvagabe for other SE-sites) and contained the URL in the headline and the body (sadly we can't see the headline in the screenshot). Posting a link twice is suspicious, posting a link in the headline is just wrong, imho. So the wimcnw-flag seems inappropriate to me here. I guess I should've gone with very low quality or custom flag. The predef. flags should be easier to handle though.

Comment: I guess with the penalty in mind it makes sense to *not* flag the question as spam. I would have thought twice about it if were written by an established user. I should probably be more forgiving to new users and generally be less strict. But these posts are so annoyingly distracting from the interesting ones. Maybe the degree of punishment should be shown next to the flags (like: spam = very angry smiley), so we better understand the consequences of flagging.

Comment: You can always hop in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room to get some extra eyeballs on SPAM questions. The regulars there have a pretty high success rate on spam flags.

Comment: This is every other question in the [tag:seo] tag.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the post was an attempt at spam. It seemed to me like a confused new user just wanted help with their website. Like an unfortunate percentage of the users that come to SO, they haven't read the help center/tour (and they probably don't know enough English to understand it if they did).

Let me address the points you have made:

> [It's] aggressively promoting the domain in both the title and the content

I wouldn't call it "aggressively promoting". They only mentioned it twice, and they likely don't have any other posts.

It's not unheard of for people in their question to link to their website that they need help with (but it's not encouraged, due to concerns about security and link rot).

And I think that they included the domain in the title in a way that's similar to how other users include the name of their project in the title.

> "exists only to promote a product or service"

Spam takes many forms, so it's possible that it could have taken this form. But I think it's far more likely that it's actually a person struggling with making a website, not a spammer masquerading as one.

> it did not properly "disclose the author's affiliation."

Actually, after you piece together the sentence, it's clear that they said that they needed help with *their* website. The logical thing to conclude would be that the link lead there.

> As far as I can see it had the tag simply to have any tag

Without reading the wiki, one might naïvely conclude that "google-app-engine" refers to the engine behind Google searches. If you look at the question, it's clear that it involves Google somehow.

> Also it did not give any kind of context, so there is no way we could've been able to answer the question without tons of comments, which would've been off-topic on Stack Overflow anyway.

Well, obviously. The first thing that you mentioned was that "it asks an off-topic question". The close reason agrees.

> I did not want to flag the question as off-topic since moving it to any other Stack Exchange site would've been pointless.

Yes, I understand your confusion (but that's a meta post I don't want to bring attention to). The options directly on the off topic menu are not for migration (migration is under "this belongs on another post in the SE network"). I HATE the design, and I think that saying "you could get help on SU/SF" just causes the same crap to be posted over there. But that's an entirely different issue.

---

TL;DR:

It's not spam, just a confused noob.

Comment: I understand the points you make but i don't fully aggree with all of them. Spam tends to come from new users since spammers don't build up rep in SO. I'm not so forgiving when it comes to ignoring rules, they exist for a reason. Not knowing the rules should not add a protective layer. A language barrier is sad, but also no excuse - usually there are discussion groups or similar in the native language which would be the better destination when you can't properly phrase a question and won't understand the answers (not an issue here). I wonder how this question made it through triage.